# WCF with Entity Framework 6.0 error "The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have upgraded a code example of .NET 4 and EF 4 from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/434282/A-N-Tier-Architecture-Sample-with-ASP-NET-MVC3-WCF) to the newest .Net Framework and EF.  I can make it work after upgraded it to .NET 4.5 but failed to further upgrade to EF6.0.

Only a few places, such as replace "using System.Data.Objects" with "using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects", need to be modified to pass the compiler after upgraded to EF6.  But the problem is that exception is thrown when execute the application.  I believe the communication between WCF and EF6 have problems.  And it is not timeout issue.

The exception types are "System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" and "System.Net.WebException, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089".

And the stack trace is -

```
System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&amp; msgData, Int32 type)
**GH.Northwind.Business.Interfaces.INorthwindSvr.GetProducts()
GH.Northwind.Web.Controllers.NorthwindController.AllProducts(AllProductsModel allProductsModel)
lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )**
System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass15.&lt;InvokeActionMethodWithFilters&gt;b__12()
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass15.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass17.&lt;InvokeActionMethodWithFilters&gt;b__14()
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass6.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClassb.&lt;BeginProcessRequest&gt;b__5()
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass1.&lt;MakeVoidDelegate&gt;b__0()
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass8`1.&lt;BeginSynchronous&gt;b__7(IAsyncResult _)
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClasse.&lt;EndProcessRequest&gt;b__d()
System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.&lt;GetCallInAppTrustThunk&gt;b__0(Action f)
System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action)
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&amp; completedSynchronously)
System.Web.HttpApplication.ApplicationStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)
System.Web.HttpApplication.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr)
System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNoDemand(HttpWorkerRequest wr)
System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequest(HttpWorkerRequest wr)
Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Request.Process()
Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Host.ProcessRequest(Connection conn)
```

I have googled around but could not found a solution. Microsoft Service Trace Tool does not help with much information.

I appreciate it if anyone can help.

Thanks

Comment: Is the WCF endpoint HTTPS? This looks like a issue with a invalid certificate.

Comment: @JonathanHolland, No.  The endpoints are just http.  They are just "http://localhost:55555/NorthwindDataService.svc" and "http://localhost:55556/NorthwindSvr.svc".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like OData related components needed to be upgraded also ([See this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2013/10/02/using-wcf-data-services-5-6-0-with-entity-framework-6.aspx)).